# Set session property for UTF-8 support globally

Tags: java, session, utf-8, jakarta-mail, mime

The latest version of JavaMail 1.6.0 has introduced a new session property for enabling UTF8 support in mail addresses. (see [changelog](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/JavaMail-1.6-changes.txt))

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.mime.allowutf8", true);
Session.getInstance(props)
```

We want to enable UTF-8 support globally in our project and a lot of classes (and libraries) create their own JavaMail sessions. Is it possible, to set a default value for a session property? Using a DefaultSession does not seem to be an option for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the cooperation of the applications, there's no way to do this.  Since this property should only be set when using a mail server that also supports the required extensions, setting it globally would not be safe.